# How can I optimize the below hash function to prevent collision

Tags: c#

How can I optimize the below hash function to prevent collision.

```
for (hashval = 0; *word != '\0'; word++)
{
    hashval enter code here= *word + 3 ;
    key = hashval % 100;
    return key ;   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not prevent hash colissions, they invariably happen. With a fixed amount of possible outputs and a unlimited amount of possible input (the [actuall definition for a hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function)), colissions are a inevitability.

Creating, debugging and fixing a hash algorythm is also not a normal programmers job. That is a job for mathematicians first and foremost. There is never a good reason to implement your own hashing algorythm. The existing ones are going to be better. They are designed and tested by groups of specialists from different fields. Your only goal should be to implement them, but even here you are very prone to errors. And should propably leave it to framework and library writers wherever possible.